# Django Piston - Is there a login_required decorator? If not, how do we raise errors?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-piston

I can't figure out for the life of me how to ensure a user is authenticated in Piston.  Here's what I've tried.

1. Login_required decorator in Piston. This doesn't seem to work, so I looked and found authentication in Piston.
2. HTTPBasicAuthentication seems to log a user in, rather than ensures a user is_authenticated. I just want to make sure they're authenticated before posting data.
3. Wrote code manually to check if user.is_authenticated. But then when a user is not authenticated, how do I raise an error that is consistent with Piston's error response?

After this, I was stuck. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: ok, I figured out the error part. At the very least, I can do this manually. In case anyone wants to know, it's this.

```
from piston.utils import rc
resp = rc.BAD_REQUEST
resp.write("Need to be logged in yo")
return resp
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create a separate handler for your anonymous clients in your handlers.py extending `piston.handler.AnonymousBaseHandler`, like described [here](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!anonymous-resources).
- Setup the `Resource` in your urls.py using the `authentication` parameter, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297125/basic-http-authentication-with-django-piston).

edit:
Actually by loggin a user in `piston.authentication.HttpBasicAuthentication` *does* ensure the user is_authenticated. Try this

```
def read(self, request):
    return {'user': request.user.is_authenticated()}
```

in your handler and test it with `curl -u user:password <url>`
You'll get

```
{
    "user": true
}
```

in your response body.

Answer (score 0):

Your error part works but you're returning a 400 status code by doing that which is a Bad Request, would be more "RESTful" to return a 401 status code which is Unauthorized.

```
    resp = HttpResponse("Authorization Required")
    resp.status_code = 401
```

Here's a listing of all the status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html